# cant get passed parameter by url in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, parameters

please help me,  this is simple thing but I don't know why this still keep error for an hour,

on my view I've got :

```
<a href="admin/editProduct?idd=$id">
```

on my controller that directed from above :

```
public function editProduct(){

        $data["id"] = $_GET['idd'];

        $data["produk"] = $this->model_get->get_data_list(2);
//this below doesn't work either, i just want to past the parameter to my model
        //$data["produk"] = $this->model_get->get_data_list($_GET['idd']);

        $this->adminHeader();
        $this->load->view("adminPages/editProduct", $data);
        $this->adminFooter();
    }
```

I can not use the array id. It keeps telling me `undefined variable` idd.
I don't know what to do anymore, please anyone help!
I am using Codeigniter framework

Comment: Take the time to format your code properly. You don't need to ask for help, it's noisy and prevents us from focusing purely on the question and your issue. Please do the necessary edits. [More data on questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In your view, you should pass  `<a href="admin/editProduct?idd=<?php echo $id;?>">` to be safe. Are you sure your `$id` in view has any value?

Comment: yes, im sure, its from my product page and work, then i need to go edit page n passing the id, n that passing is confusing, keep telling me undefined

Comment: m just asking now, if i use <a href="web/controller/method?id=$id] > so i catch that parameter id in my controller using $_GET["id"] right ??

Answer (score 1):

Change your view as:

```
<a href="admin/editProduct/<?php echo $id;?>">
```

And in the controller, either get the id as parameter,

```
  public function editProduct($id) {
  }
```

or as uri segment

```
  public function editProduct() {
      $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your link (in view) with this

```
<a href="admin/editProduct/$id">
```

And change your controller as

```
public function editProduct($id) {

}
```

Then user `$id` inside your controller

Answer (score 0):

Make the href link as follows:

```
<a href="admin/editProduct/$id">...</a>
```

And edit the controller like this:

```
public function editProduct($id){
    ...
    $this->model_get->get_data_list($id); 
}
```

Where $id will be the passed $id.

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: id
i understand what u mean, i just dont know why this still error,

Comment: Make sure that the anchor tag generated properly from your side.

Comment: im just asking now, 
if i use <a href="web/controller/method?id=$id] >
so i catch that parameter id in my controller using $_GET["id"] right ??

Comment: case closed, ive got it, thank you very much for your time Mr Kumar

Answer (score 0):

make

try this this works fine

```
  public function editProduct()
     { 
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3); 
        $data["produk"] = $this->model_get->get_data_list($id);
        $this->adminHeader();
        $this->load->view("adminPages/editProduct", $data);
        $this->adminFooter();
    }
```